# SQL Server: Export Databases Locally at Specific Time

Tags: sql-server

We are taking full disk backup of our servers weekly. How do I set up SQL Server 2016 to export all databases automatically to a local folder, every Friday at 6 PM? I'd like to do that to add extra level of protection against database corruption.

Comment: if you are taking database back ups from your database servers, why are you also doing full disk back ups? What more can be gained by having the databases backed up twice? You can put the database on it's own partition and exclude that from disk back up.

Comment: That server has multiple roles, not just SQL Server. I'm talking about already reliably working backups, and our databases are pretty small, so why not just export them once a week? It's not like it costs extra money, but saves time that I can spend on some other tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Ola Hallengren's scripts for database backups. https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

Remember to DBCC check database before taking a backup and to both validate the backup media and to try your restore scenarios frequently!

Here are the steps from the FAQ:

1. Download MaintenanceSolution.sql.
2. In the script, find this line:
   SET @BackupDirectory = N'C:\Backup'
   and replace C:\Backup with the path to your backup directory.
3. In the script, find this line:
   SET @CleanupTime = NULL 
   and replace NULL with your cleanup time. The cleanup time is the the number of hours after which the backup files are deleted.
4. Execute MaintenanceSolution.sql. This script creates all the objects and jobs that you need.
5. Go into [SQL Server Agent] / [Jobs] and start the jobs that have been created. Verify that these jobs are completing successfully. Verify that the backup files are being created. Check the output files in the error log directory.
6. Schedule the jobs.

Comment: Thanks, David! Is the method reliable? Would you happen to know other best practices for my use case?